# Any better way to check validity before onChange React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I want to validate my input before passing it to onChange function from react-hook-form. Especially for input case like only accept number. I just tried with this snippet below, but I figure out if there are another better way.

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="nik"
  rules={PERSONAL_INFORMATION_FORM_SCHEMA.nik}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <TextField
      {...field}
      error={!!errors?.nik}
      helperText={errors.nik?.message}
      id="nik"
      name="nik"
      placeholder={t("personalInformationInputIDNumberPlaceholder")}
      type="text"
      inputProps={{
        pattern: "[0-9]*",
        maxLength: 16
      }}
      onChange={event => field.onChange(validateInput(event))}
    />
  )}
/>
```